# Modify the width of a tab in a format string

Tags: python

Is it possible to redefine the space width of a tab when printing a `\t` character in python?

Comment: The closest you're going to get is `print string.replace('\t', ' '*n)`

Comment: Oo, this will actually work for my purposes.. thanks.

Comment: @wim I'm glad that helps him, but that is very much not the same. If you want a tab shown as four spaces, `abc\t` will be not `abc_` but `abc____` with that replacement.

Comment: only if you don't dynamically calculate n :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `pydoc string.expandtabs`, I think it will do what you want.

Comment: example: `print "1\t2\t3".expandtabs(4)`

Comment: Thanks for giving the example with tabs set at four columns, @BrianD, that's something I should have included.

Answer (score 9):

Python's `print` feature does not convert tabs to spaces - it outputs a literal tab. The way it appears depends on what program you use to view it.

Comment: Guess I should have known that.